# How to access cell properties outside of declaration function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have created a tableView that returns a cell. I want to be able to change the cell properties outside of the dequeReusableCells function. I have tried this:

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
let refCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index)
refCell?.textLabel?.textColor = .white
```

but it only changes the textLabel color to white for the second cell. How can I do this for all cells (other than using a for loop)?

Comment: you can do it in the custom cell class

Comment: you could use a tableview delegate method like `willDisplayCell`...

Comment: `I want to be able to change the cell properties outside of the dequeReusableCells function.` Why? What's your goal exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for changing all `UITableViewCells` you should create

```
fileprivate var myColor: UIColor = .black
```

inside `UIViewController`

then inside `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = self.myColor
```

then whenever you want to change this color just do

```
self.myColor = .white
self.myTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: This works for the text, but the cell background color won't change. I'm doing: `cell.backgroundColor = self.myColor`, but the cell background color won't change

Comment: But when I do: `cell.backgroundColor = .red` it changes to red

Comment: I figured out the issue. Thanks for the help!